# Separate vendor and app bundles with angular2 and browserify - Import error

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, browserify, tsify

I'm working on an angular2 app that I want to build using gulp and browserify.
Using [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify) I managed to output a standalone `bundle.js`, at a glorious size of 1.4M after minification.

What I would like to have is **two separate bundle files: one for vendor dependencies and one for my app**.

Basically I was hoping to achieve this:

```
  <!-- My dream index.html script tags -->
  <script src="bundle_vendors.js"></script>
  <script src="bundle_app.js"></script>
```

Here's what I tried on the command line:

1. I generated a first bundle:

   ```
   browserify app/vendor.ts -p [tsify ] > bundle_vendors.js
   ```

My vendor.ts file is just a list of imports:

```
import 'zone.js'
import 'reflect-metadata'
import '@angular/core'
import '@angular/http'
import '@angular/router'
import '@angular/common'
import '@angular/platform-browser'
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import 'rxjs/Rx'
```

2. Then I created my second bundle:

   ```
   browserify -x @angular/core -x @angular/common -x @angular/http -x @angular/router -x rxjs/Rx -x @angular/platform-browser -x zone.js -x reflect-metadata -x @angular/platform-browser-dynamic app/main.ts -p [tsify ] > bundle_app.js
   ```

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like this (it lives in the current directory):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],  
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

**The good part**: The second bundle contains only my app and it is much smaller!
**The not-so-good part**: It does not work. I'm the browser I get an `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'`.

Onto the questions:

- Is there something obvious I'm missing?
- How can I see the modules that are available for `require` after I loaded the `bundle_vendors.js`? I'm looking for the list of modules that are 'exported' so other bundles can import them.

I have no clue where to start debugging this.

From what I read an alternative would be to use angular-cli (which uses webpack), but the project I work on already uses gulp so I'd like to make it work. Plus I'm kinda committed now.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You definitely want to be using angular-cli. Angular-cli will automatically create your bundles for you. It will also tree-shake, minify, and perform many other optimizations for you. No need for gulp. Seriously, I promise you, angular-cli is where you want to be.

Comment: I got something working with gulp & browserify for the bundling part (though bundles are HUGE), but then the `watchify` part was sluggish... Terrible developing experience.  
I'm sure it can be solved with time/more skills, but as you mentioned that's not where I want to be ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You have not used the [`-r` option](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#brequirefile-opts) for the modules you wish to require from `bundle_vendors.js`.
2. There is a bug in tsify that breaks Browserify's `-r` option.

I've fixed the second problem and a new version of tsify (3.0.0) has been publised to NPM.

To fix the first, you should change the command used to build `bundle_vendors.js` to:

```
browserify -r @angular/core -r @angular/common -r @angular/http -r @angular/router -r rxjs/Rx -r @angular/platform-browser -r zone.js -r reflect-metadata -r @angular/platform-browser-dynamic app/vendor.ts -p [tsify] > bundle_vendors.js
```

Also, you might want to consider adding the [`skipLibCheck` compiler option](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new---skiplibcheck) to your `tsconfig.json`:

> TypeScript 2.0 adds a new `--skipLibCheck` compiler option that causes type checking of declaration files (files with extension `.d.ts`) to be skipped. When a program includes large declaration files, the compiler spends a lot of time type checking declarations that are already known to not contain errors, and compile times may be significantly shortened by skipping declaration file type checks.

Comment: Thanks, 1. was definitely the main issue. I was expecting browserify to export the modules from `bundle_vendors.js`. Not sure why now that I think about it, it's only in the next command that I tell browserify I want to use them (with `-x`).  
Actually I tried using `-r` after writing my question, and I'm pretty sure I got it working with the same command you wrote, **without tsify for the first step**. I guess browserify was able to figure out where the relevant javascript files were so it did not need typescript.